# Javascript Confirm not working in Godaddy

Tags: javascript, html

From here,
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  confirm("Press a button!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works well. But when I try it in Godaddy HTML block. It does not work.In Godaddy, Button is seen but when I click button nothing happens so it does not work although design is not problematic.

How can I make it work? Is it possible to run confirm method in Godaddy HTML Block? In fact I can run different Javascript features / code like local storage or `document.execCommand("copy");` without any problem in Godaddy. But Javascript confirm method does not working in Godaddy. How can we solve it?

**Edit:** You can provide alternative solution to ask user "yes" - "no" question in Godaddy by using Javascript - HTML. My aim is to ask user "Are you sure to do this?" I mean you can provide a solution rather than confirm.

Comment: Make the world a friendlier place [by not using GoDaddy](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kellyclay/2012/09/10/5-reasons-you-should-leave-godaddy-and-how/).

Comment: @Andy Thanks but it provides some useful features like e-mail marketing, seo, website builder and more. This question is not about using Godaddy or not. The problem is clear. How can make confirm() work in Godaddy?

Comment: It's not clear in what way it fails, you didn't provide a link to the live page which is broken, nor did you provide devtools console output. Please add more information, thank you! (And I don't think this has anything to do with the GoDaddy API, you don't use its API anywhere - I'm removing the tag.) - Please provide a reproducible example, ideally a link to a live page that has this issue.

Comment: What is "*Godaddy HTML block*"?

Comment: @CherryDT [Not just a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi In this case _yes_ a link (not "just" - the code is already here). The issue is that whatever environment this code is run in interferes with the script, so we would need to see it "in the wild" failing so that we can open devtools and investigate. Usually it's the other way round, but not this time - the code alone doesn't help, because it would work just fine. Maybe there is CSP in play? Maybe it's a sandboxed IFrame? Maybe the HTML is sanitized and scripts removed? Maybe an unrelated global var `confirm` is defined by an injected script? No way to tell without seeing the live page.

Comment: @CherryDT I don't see why the rules would void here. They need to accurately describe the environment they're running this in, in the question itself; ideally providing a link to the documentation of their environment. Asking to debug some code running in the wild is off-topic, a bounty doesn't change that.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't say the rules are void, I also didn't say they should post _only_ a link. Extra info never hurts. If I were to identify the problem based on the live page I'd include an explanation for it in my answer, at which point the link would be useless again, and all the info would exist in writing. But clearly the OP is not able to understand their own environment that exact technical way in which we'd need it, and to then answer the question we would have to possibly open an account with GoDaddy and follow steps to reproduce - I don't think this way the OP will ever get an answer...

Comment: "Asking to debug some code running in the wild is off-topic, a bounty doesn't change that." < The way I see it, my knowledge exists in a "compiled form" in my brain, the value of it is the ability to take the right troubleshooting steps and come to the right conclusions. I cannot transfer this knowledge easily on its own but I can _apply_ it and answer questions this way, and then _future_ questions (issues with scripts not working in GoDaddy) _can_ refer to the result of that, because it will now exist in distilled form as an answer writeup...

Comment: @CherryDT "*the OP is not able to understand their own environment that exact technical way in which we'd need it*" - yes. I applaud your desire to help, but I think such questions are simply not a good fit for StackOverflow. They should rather ask in a godaddy forum or get their customer service.

Comment: Good point. You are right, thank you.

Comment: @Bergi I asked but I get no answer. I think StackOverflow developers are the best in the world. That's why I asked here because they know better than Godaddy customer service. Besides some people may encounter this confirm working problem in Godaddy so this question may be a good guide for them. The queston and problem is clear most of javascript code work without any problem in Godaddy HTML block but confirm does not work. When I click the button nothing happens in my website when it works well in w3schools. (SAME code)

Comment: @Bergi What is HTML block? As we know Godaddy provides a website builder. In website builder there is a section HTML block. We can write HTML, Javascript & CSS codes here and it works without any problem generally. But confirm() method does not work interestingly when execcommand("copy"); method works well in Godaddy HTML block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Use a library, like [`vex.js`](https://github.hubspot.com/vex/):

```js
vex.defaultOptions.className = 'vex-theme-default';
vex.dialog.confirm({
    message: 'Press a button!',
    callback: function (value) {
        console.log(value ? "OK" : "CANCEL");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/4.1.0/js/vex.combined.min.js" integrity="sha512-9ZP47jSudEgrUZA1Z3VOWIJFxHCfkJlarrrQxVdPH/vVtoAwD84AS8lmiv0hizWQvFkwAUnYZA/nehKRP5EFUg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/4.1.0/css/vex-theme-default.min.css" integrity="sha512-DR1rAGpnA4hKCYcnKwgANJLco6nw5VjZPFGx1Li7vjyxSDq0Bh7neUIxMc+LdAb7zUjrA0bZ9ZX/9wesaKl/QQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: It is not working.. https://i.ibb.co/BjZr5F2/Ekran-Resmi-2021-05-31-22-29-58.png Could you provide full code please that is working in w3schools?

Comment: @gurkanstack Move the JS into a seperate script tag. Check it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GR302OXUNVS1

Comment: so what happens if user clicks OK? How can I handle it? Your code is working but could you provide commented code?(that explains what happens if OK or CANCEL is clicked)

Comment: @gurkanstack No problem. It originally logged the result into the console. Here's a more obvious example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GR308M0NSYVG

Answer (score 1):

Since there is lack of information from DevTools Console output or at least the screenshot of where the HTML Block in typed. I'm going with a custom HTML/JavaScript approach, as you also mentioned

> You can provide alternative solution to ask user "yes" - "no" question in GoDaddy by using JavaScript - HTML. My aim is to ask user "Are you sure to do this?" I mean you can provide a solution rather than confirm.

So I'm providing an alternative approach for confirm prompt. Check this out.

```js
function customConfirm(context, onConfirm, confirmText, cancelText) {
  var dialog = document.createElement("dialog");
  dialog.innerText = context;

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var yes = document.createElement("button");
  var no = document.createElement("button");
  yes.innerText = confirmText || "YES";
  no.innerText = cancelText || "NO";


  div.appendChild(no);
  div.appendChild(yes);
  dialog.appendChild(div);
  document.body.appendChild(dialog);

  yes.onclick = function() {
    dialog.close();
    onConfirm(true)
  }
  no.onclick = function() {
    dialog.close();
    onConfirm(false)
  }
  dialog.showModal();
}

customConfirm("This is dialog box asking for the confirmation from user.", (confirmed) => {
  document.body.innerHTML = "User clicked:" + (confirmed ? "YES" : "NO");
}, "Confirm", "Cancel")
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

You can use this `customConfirm()` function to prompt the User for confirmation.
First parameter is the dialog content and second parameter is a callback function that runs when user responds with response as parameter.

Callback function fires with `true` when user responds positively and `false` when user negatively responds.

> Also you can set the Dialog Buttons' text optionally by passing in 3rd
> and 4th parameters